# JS nested object access to global variables

Tags: javascript, json, global-variables

I have an JavaScript object defined as following...

```
    var f = {
        test: 'myTestContent',
        app: {
            base: {
                action: function () {
                    alert(test);
                }            
            }
        }
    };

    f.app.base.action();
```

The problem is that I cannot access the **test** variable as defined in the **f** instance. Is it possible to access variables in this context from nested objects?

At the moment I get **test** is undefined. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Try `f.test` (BTW -- `test` is not a global variable)

Comment: Correct. `test` is actually not a variable–it is a property of the object stored in the variable `f`.

Comment: There's no way to automatically get access to a "parent" object from a method of the "child" (because really although the "parent" has a reference to the "child" it doesn't actually own it - other objects could also have references to the same "child"). `test` isn't global the way your question sort of implies, it is a property of `f` so you can say `f.test`.

Comment: Is is somehow possible to define test to be global. Maybe another construction of defining the f instance?

Answer (score 4):

`test` isn't defined globally. You'd have to use the proper reference:

```
alert(f.test);
```

Should work.

Answer (score 2):

`test` is not a global variable, rather it is a property of `f`. So you want:

```
var f = {
    test: 'myTestContent',
    app: {
        base: {
            action: function () {
                alert(f.test);  // Notice this line.
            }            
        }
    }
};

f.app.base.action();
```

Access it just like you access `f.app` on the last line.

Comment: _"f, which is global"_ - unless the code in the question is inside a function. But yes, `f.test` will work either way.

Comment: I could pass the parent object to the child elements, but I'm trying to find a better solution for that. See example bellow of my usage... The problem is when creating copies of such an instance where the test parameter is not the same...